# DbFunctions or similar to compare time of day of a datetime type column in Linq to Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, sqldatetime, dbfunctions

I know there is a function to compare just the date of a datetime type column, but what if I want to only compare the time of it to another time.  Is there a function in Linq To Entities?

```
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(q.EndDate.Value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this and it worked fine.

```
SqlFunctions.DatePart("hh", t.Time.Value) == SqlFunctions.DatePart("hh", newTime) && SqlFunctions.DatePart("n", t.Time.Value) == SqlFunctions.DatePart("n", newTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but you can use a combination of a `Diff` variant method with `TruncateTime`. For example, to compare a time down to the second:

```
DbFunctions.DiffSeconds(DbFunctions.TrucateTime(x.Date1), x.Date1) -
    DbFunctions.DiffSeconds(DbFunctions.TrucateTime(x.Date2), x.Date2) == 0
```

Would tell you if the two times (on different dates) are the same or not.